# url forwarding on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a flask app on aws and am trying to set up url forwarding correctly from my domain name to the aws url.

Ideally I would like a mapping something like this:

```
Example.com ----> myapp-env.******.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com

Example.com/mosaic ---> myapp-env.******.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/mosaic

Example.com/mosaic/uploader ---> myapp-env.******.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/mosaic/uploader
```

However, I'm only getting the correct mapping for pages I go to directly, not for links.

To go from one page to another, I have links in html that when submitted will do a post request.

However, if the link is to my personal domain then it will send the user to the index. Like `Example.com/mosaic ----> Example.com` (where the example.com -->myapp-env.******.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com mapping is still true, so it shows index page, w/ example.com in the url bar)

If I put the aws address into the form then this works as expected, with the aws address is in the url bar.

Here is an example form action:
      http://example.com/mosaic/uploader" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">

Also possibly relevant:

My domain name is registered with google, where I have a subdomain foward of example.com -> http://www.example.com, and a CNAME record with a host of www and value of http://wwww.myapp-env.******.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com

Is there anything I need to configure on aws?

Comment: You should check in devtools if there is an redirect happening to index page.

Comment: How would I check this? I looked at html, sources, network, application of the index page after redirect and the page from before the redirect and didn't see anything that seemed relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved itself when I created simpler test cases and fixed various bugs in my code related to the links.